# ListPlot3D introducing artifacts into surface

Tags: plotting

I solved a set of cubic polynomials and got a set of discrete points for plotting a 3D surface. Using `ListPlot3D`, I got the surface; but somehow, the plot has extra and undesirable surfaces towards the end of the 'time' variable domain. I checked out the code, and the points generated; but could not find any reason as to why these extra surfaces were getting generated. I tried limiting the time domain, but the surface still shows up with the same problems.

I then separately plotted 2D graphs versus the 'x' variable domain and another one versus the 't' variable domain. The variation of the dependent variable 'Gamma33' is almost a constant with time. This should obviously mean that the 3D surface should only be an extension of the first plot (`Gamma33` vs `x`) along the time domain. But what I get as the surface shows a difference, which I cannot understand.

Is it a problem with my code or the way I have complied the points generated? I've been stuck with this problem for a few days now; so it would be of great help if you guys could help me correct my errors.

P.S.: I'm just getting started on Mathematica, so please do forgive any of my mistakes you come across. It would be of great help if you'd come out to correct me. I have given the points generated as a list 'data6' below.

[image]

#### Edit

I'm really sorry for all inconveniences caused by not providing the data.

```
 data6 = Flatten[{{{0.315`, 0, 0.0002091894601197712`}, {0.312`, 0, 
 0.00019387690925177074`}, {0.309`, 0, 
 0.00017856437305779457`}, {0.306`, 0, 
 0.00016325185126184124`}, {0.303`, 0, 
 0.00014793934358790995`}, {0.3`, 0, 
 0.00013262684975999991`}, {0.315`, 720, 
 0.0002091894601197712`}, {0.312`, 720, 
 0.00019387690925177074`}, {0.309`, 720, 
 0.00017856437305779457`}, {0.306`, 720, 
 0.00016325185126184126`}, {0.303`, 720, 
 0.00014793934358790995`}, {0.3`, 720, 
 0.0001326268497599999`}, {0.315`, 1440, 
 0.0002091894601197712`}, {0.312`, 1440, 
 0.00019387690925177074`}, {0.309`, 1440, 
 0.00017856437305779457`}, {0.306`, 1440, 
 0.00016325185126184126`}, {0.303`, 1440, 
 0.00014793934358790995`}, {0.3`, 1440, 
 0.0001326268497599999`}, {0.315`, 2160, 
 0.0002091894601197712`}, {0.312`, 2160, 
 0.00019387690925177074`}, {0.309`, 2160, 
 0.00017856437305779457`}, {0.306`, 2160, 
 0.00016325185126184126`}, {0.303`, 2160, 
 0.00014793934358790995`}, {0.3`, 2160, 
 0.0001326268497599999`}, {0.315`, 2880, 
 0.0002091894601197712`}, {0.312`, 2880, 
 0.00019387690925177074`}, {0.309`, 2880, 
 0.00017856437305779457`}, {0.306`, 2880, 
 0.00016325185126184126`}, {0.303`, 2880, 
 0.00014793934358790995`}, {0.3`, 2880, 
 0.0001326268497599999`}, {0.315`, 3600, 
 0.0002091894601197712`}, {0.312`, 3600, 
 0.00019387690925177074`}, {0.309`, 3600, 
 0.00017856437305779457`}, {0.306`, 3600, 
 0.00016325185126184126`}, {0.303`, 3600, 
 0.00014793934358790995`}, {0.3`, 3600, 
 0.0001326268497599999`}}, {{0.3`, 0, 
 0.00009946918437999995`}, {0.298`, 0, 
 0.00009180343562724633`}, {0.296`, 0, 
 0.00008413769052433911`}, {0.294`, 0, 
 0.0000764719490211087`}, {0.292`, 0, 
 0.00006880621106738548`}, {0.29`, 0, 
 0.00006114047661299987`}, {0.3`, 720, 
 0.00008211459237999995`}, {0.298`, 720, 
 0.00007444884362724634`}, {0.296`, 720, 
 0.00006678309852433913`}, {0.294`, 720, 
 0.0000591173570211087`}, {0.292`, 720, 
 0.00005145161906738549`}, {0.29`, 720, 
 0.00004378588461299988`}, {0.3`, 1440, 
 0.00006476000037999996`}, {0.298`, 1440, 
 0.00005709425162724634`}, {0.296`, 1440, 
 0.00004942850652433913`}, {0.294`, 1440, 
 0.0000417627650211087`}, {0.292`, 1440, 
 0.00003409702706738549`}, {0.29`, 1440, 
 0.000026431292612999875`}, {0.3`, 2160, 
 0.00004740540837999995`}, {0.298`, 2160, 
 0.00003973965962724634`}, {0.296`, 2160, 
 0.00003207391452433913`}, {0.294`, 2160, 
 0.0000244081730211087`}, {0.292`, 2160, 
 0.00001674243506738549`}, {0.29`, 2160, 
 9.076700612999872`*^-6}, {0.3`, 2880, 
 0.000030050816379999964`}, {0.298`, 2880, 
 0.000022385067627246342`}, {0.296`, 2880, 
 0.000014719322524339137`}, {0.294`, 2880, 
 7.053581021108709`*^-6}, {0.292`, 
 2880, -6.121569326145003`*^-7}, {0.29`, 
 2880, -8.277891387000117`*^-6}, {0.3`, 3600, 
 0.00001269622437999996`}, {0.298`, 3600, 
 5.030475627246339`*^-6}, {0.296`, 
 3600, -2.6352694756608656`*^-6}, {0.294`, 
 3600, -0.000010301010978891294`}, {0.292`, 
 3600, -0.000017966748932614503`}, {0.29`, 
 3600, -0.00002563248338700012`}}, {{0.29`, 
 0, -0.007685198811`}, {0.26199999999999996`, 
 0, -0.007045079847432`}, {0.23399999999999999`, 
 0, -0.006353384242776`}, {0.20599999999999996`, 
 0, -0.005623300451303999`}, {0.178`, 
 0, -0.004868016927288`}, {0.14999999999999997`, 
 0, -0.004100722124999999`}, {0.12199999999999997`, 
 0, -0.0033346044987119993`}, {0.09399999999999997`, 
 0, -0.0025828525026959995`}, {0.06599999999999998`, 
 0, -0.0018586545912239994`}, {0.03799999999999998`, 
 0, -0.0011751992185679995`}, {0.009999999999999953`, 
 0, -0.000545674838999999`}, {0.29`, 
 720, -0.007685198810999825`}, {0.26199999999999996`, 
 720, -0.007045079847431839`}, {0.23399999999999999`, 
 720, -0.006353384242775855`}, {0.20599999999999996`, 
 720, -0.00562330045130387`}, {0.178`, 
 720, -0.0048680169272878855`}, {0.14999999999999997`, 
 720, -0.0041007221249999`}, {0.12199999999999997`, 
 720, -0.0033346044987119156`}, {0.09399999999999997`, 
 720, -0.0025828525026959314`}, {0.06599999999999998`, 
 720, -0.0018586545912239467`}, {0.03799999999999998`, 
 720, -0.001175199218567962`}, {0.009999999999999953`, 
 720, -0.0005456748389999767`}, {0.29`, 
 1440, -0.00768519881099965`}, {0.26199999999999996`, 
 1440, -0.00704507984743168`}, {0.23399999999999999`, 
 1440, -0.006353384242775711`}, {0.20599999999999996`, 
 1440, -0.00562330045130374`}, {0.178`, 
 1440, -0.004868016927287772`}, {0.14999999999999997`, 
 1440, -0.0041007221249998015`}, {0.12199999999999997`, 
 1440, -0.0033346044987118324`}, {0.09399999999999997`, 
 1440, -0.0025828525026958633`}, {0.06599999999999998`, 
 1440, -0.0018586545912238938`}, {0.03799999999999998`, 
 1440, -0.0011751992185679244`}, {0.009999999999999953`, 
 1440, -0.0005456748389999545`}, {0.29`, 
 2160, -0.007685198810999475`}, {0.26199999999999996`, 
 2160, -0.007045079847431519`}, {0.23399999999999999`, 
 2160, -0.006353384242775566`}, {0.20599999999999996`, 
 2160, -0.00562330045130361`}, {0.178`, 
 2160, -0.004868016927287657`}, {0.14999999999999997`, 
 2160, -0.004100722124999703`}, {0.12199999999999997`, 
 2160, -0.0033346044987117487`}, {0.09399999999999997`, 
 2160, -0.0025828525026957948`}, {0.06599999999999998`, 
 2160, -0.0018586545912238409`}, {0.03799999999999998`, 
 2160, -0.001175199218567887`}, {0.009999999999999953`, 
 2160, -0.0005456748389999321`}, {0.29`, 
 2880, -0.0076851988109993`}, {0.26199999999999996`, 
 2880, -0.0070450798474313596`}, {0.23399999999999999`, 
 2880, -0.006353384242775421`}, {0.20599999999999996`, 
 2880, -0.005623300451303481`}, {0.178`, 
 2880, -0.004868016927287544`}, {0.14999999999999997`, 
 2880, -0.004100722124999605`}, {0.12199999999999997`, 
 2880, -0.0033346044987116654`}, {0.09399999999999997`, 
 2880, -0.0025828525026957267`}, {0.06599999999999998`, 
 2880, -0.001858654591223788`}, {0.03799999999999998`, 
 2880, -0.0011751992185678494`}, {0.009999999999999953`, 
 2880, -0.0005456748389999099`}, {0.29`, 
 3600, -0.0076851988109991245`}, {0.26199999999999996`, 
 3600, -0.007045079847431199`}, {0.23399999999999999`, 
 3600, -0.0063533842427752766`}, {0.20599999999999996`, 
 3600, -0.005623300451303352`}, {0.178`, 
 3600, -0.004868016927287429`}, {0.14999999999999997`, 
 3600, -0.004100722124999506`}, {0.12199999999999997`, 
 3600, -0.0033346044987115817`}, {0.09399999999999997`, 
 3600, -0.0025828525026956586`}, {0.06599999999999998`, 
 3600, -0.001858654591223735`}, {0.03799999999999998`, 
 3600, -0.0011751992185678117`}, {0.009999999999999953`, 
 3600, -0.0005456748389998877`}}, {{0.01`, 
 0, -0.00009850689601803999`}, {0.008`, 
 0, -0.00010738910172619006`}, {0.006`, 
 0, -0.00011627131487546943`}, {0.004`, 
 0, -0.00012515353556886974`}, {0.002`, 
 0, -0.0001340357639093827`}, {0.`, 0, -0.000142918`}, {0.01`, 
 720, -0.00007528156801803999`}, {0.008`, 
 720, -0.00008416377372619007`}, {0.006`, 
 720, -0.00009304598687546943`}, {0.004`, 
 720, -0.00010192820756886973`}, {0.002`, 
 720, -0.0001108104359093827`}, {0.`, 
 720, -0.00011969267199999999`}, {0.01`, 
 1440, -0.00005205624001803999`}, {0.008`, 
 1440, -0.00006093844572619006`}, {0.006`, 
 1440, -0.00006982065887546943`}, {0.004`, 
 1440, -0.00007870287956886972`}, {0.002`, 
 1440, -0.0000875851079093827`}, {0.`, 
 1440, -0.00009646734399999999`}, {0.01`, 
 2160, -0.00002883091201803998`}, {0.008`, 
 2160, -0.00003771311772619005`}, {0.006`, 
 2160, -0.00004659533087546942`}, {0.004`, 
 2160, -0.00005547755156886972`}, {0.002`, 
 2160, -0.00006435977990938269`}, {0.`, 
 2160, -0.00007324201599999998`}, {0.01`, 
 2880, -5.605584018039981`*^-6}, {0.008`, 
 2880, -0.000014487789726190054`}, {0.006`, 
 2880, -0.000023370002875469423`}, {0.004`, 
 2880, -0.00003225222356886972`}, {0.002`, 
 2880, -0.000041134451909382693`}, {0.`, 
 2880, -0.00005001668799999998`}, {0.01`, 3600, 
 0.000017619743981960018`}, {0.008`, 3600, 
 8.737538273809946`*^-6}, {0.006`, 
 3600, -1.446748754694232`*^-7}, {0.004`, 
 3600, -9.026895568869719`*^-6}, {0.002`, 
 3600, -0.000017909123909382694`}, {0.`, 
 3600, -0.00002679135999999998`}}, {{0.`, 
 0, -0.000164247`}, {-0.002`, 
 0, -0.00017445554199272542`}, {-0.004`, 
 0, -0.0001846640880055955`}, {-0.006`, 
 0, -0.00019487263809065086`}, {-0.008`, 
 0, -0.00020508119229993213`}, {-0.01`, 
 0, -0.00021528975068548`}, {0.`, 720, -0.000164247`}, {-0.002`, 
 720, -0.00017445554199272542`}, {-0.004`, 
 720, -0.00018466408800559553`}, {-0.006`, 
 720, -0.00019487263809065086`}, {-0.008`, 
 720, -0.00020508119229993213`}, {-0.01`, 
 720, -0.00021528975068548`}, {0.`, 
 1440, -0.000164247`}, {-0.002`, 
 1440, -0.00017445554199272542`}, {-0.004`, 
 1440, -0.00018466408800559553`}, {-0.006`, 
 1440, -0.00019487263809065086`}, {-0.008`, 
 1440, -0.00020508119229993213`}, {-0.01`, 
 1440, -0.00021528975068548`}, {0.`, 
 2160, -0.000164247`}, {-0.002`, 
 2160, -0.00017445554199272542`}, {-0.004`, 
 2160, -0.00018466408800559553`}, {-0.006`, 
 2160, -0.00019487263809065086`}, {-0.008`, 
 2160, -0.00020508119229993213`}, {-0.01`, 
 2160, -0.00021528975068548`}, {0.`, 
 2880, -0.000164247`}, {-0.002`, 
 2880, -0.00017445554199272542`}, {-0.004`, 
 2880, -0.00018466408800559553`}, {-0.006`, 
 2880, -0.00019487263809065086`}, {-0.008`, 
 2880, -0.00020508119229993213`}, {-0.01`, 
 2880, -0.00021528975068548`}, {0.`, 
 3600, -0.000164247`}, {-0.002`, 
 3600, -0.00017445554199272542`}, {-0.004`, 
 3600, -0.00018466408800559553`}, {-0.006`, 
 3600, -0.00019487263809065086`}, {-0.008`, 
 3600, -0.00020508119229993213`}, {-0.01`, 
 3600, -0.00021528975068548`}}}, 1]
```

To check out the points generated, I used `ListPointPlot3D` and got a result which I have attached as the second image. As is very evident, none of these points lie within the 'undesirable' surfaces generated. So why does this problem arise while using `ListPlot3D`?

```
 ListPlot3D[data6]
```

[image]

Comment: As already noted, your problem is unanswerable if you do not provide the code to reproduce your plot.

Comment: Anyone wanting to help should consider the results of `Show[ListPlot3D[data6], Graphics3D@{Red, Point@data6}]` and `Interpolation[data6, InterpolationOrder -> 1]`